# Run and pass some parameter to stored procedures from trigger

Tags: c#, sql, sockets, model-view-controller

I'm developing a real-time project about vehicle tracking with `tcpip` socket and MVC. The socket inserted data from GPS to SQL Server, but when inserting a string of GPS, I have some process

For example, check over speed and out of range and ... if I want only insert string inside of the socket and write code of check, some data of GPS device string inside of SQL Server.

Can I write a trigger for that table when inserted record and pass some column of the row as a parameter to stored procedures for check data and process,...

If you have better Ideas about reducing process inside the socket, please guide me

Comment: What do you mean by `inside the socket`? From what i understand you are receiving some messages ( via `tcp` protocol ) and you want to process them and maybe store them in a `SQL Database`.  By triggers you mean you want your database to perform a custom query whenerver a condition is fulfilled as a result of insertion of a said message?

Comment: My mean When i Want  Insert String of gps in  SQL Server  check over speed and .... then after check then insert their data in their table

Comment: Check my answer

Comment: You want to use the Socket Asynchronous Read method and do the processing when receiving the data.  You can either write the data to the database and then do your processing, or do the processing and then write to the database.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/socket-code-examples

Comment: I Used Thread in my sockect

Answer (score 2):

Inside a trigger you have full access to the data inserted. So you can call a stored procedure from inside trigger and pass data to it. That's no problem. But you don't want to do this, because it slows down your socket process. Therefore you're asking for some other solution. I maybe would create an independent worker process that does the heavy calculation work.

But the most important suggestion here is - take a step back and architect your application correctly. From your question I see that you did not solve this part of your development process:

- Using triggers for implementing business logic is a very bad idea - they should be used with care.
- Your question, as far as I understand it, is not about MVC so why do you tag it with *model-view-controller*
- The business logic (tracking vehicles) will at least partially be solved inside the data store.

Comment: ok thnx for your answer whats your idea for reducing  process inside socket,process inside socket or used timer inside server for check table changes or ...., please guide me

Comment: using a timer might be a simple solution - yes. But is it what you need? Do you track five or so vehicles? Does the app need to scale and serve for thousands of vehicles? Then a timed process would not work stable anymore. Using message queues or some cloud based technology could be beneficial. I come back to my statement: First Architect your application, know your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

A `socket` identifies an endpoint in a network.It is characterized by 4 "components":

```
-source ip
-source port
-destination ip 
-destination port
```

When you `open` a socket your os returns you a `filedescriptor` (handle) for the file where the incoming  data arrives.

Now coming back to your scenario  i understood that you are receiving data via the `tcp` protocol and you want to :

```
-insert said data into a `SQL Database`
-execute custom logic  based on some triggers.
```

I sketched a simple diagram for what i believe is you want:

[image]

So your gps data would get directly inserted in your database on one hand.

Now regarding the triggers.Yould could do them directly from `SQL`, or you could perform the checking in the server and then just call a stored procedure for the rest of your logic.

Comment: my first scenario  is when recived data from  gps and check it is correct string then insert directly in data base because  may be many gps  dveice sent data  and data in queue then  with timer or trriger that data inserted in table if that data for example have over speed or ... then insert over speed message in over speed table, but i dont know this scenario its good or not if its not good i want better idea , if you can help me

Comment: Could you provide some information on what is the end goal  of your solution ? What does this application need to do ?

Comment: my application  will should track many  carrier of Organizations and  should control over speed and out of range of geofence and  Vehicle weight  and anothor parameter that sent by gps device, and if  each of parameters  is out of range then will send message to central control